# how to concat our website url in our bit coin transaction in blockchain send api

Tags: api, blockchain.info, message

Hi im using block chain send api in my web application, and it is working fine without any issues. My requirements is when the payment is done thought blockchain send api, is it possible to concat our website url with custom name in the transaction?

In this address `https://blockchain.info/address/1H7FMLas2d7HqSstx8xVDMURvWphv4bnFd` user has concatinated his website name with url.

How can i do the same using send api?

Comment: can't this be done via the $node parameter?

Answer (score 1):

### Address Tag

There are two ways I know of to tag an address on blockchain.info but both require a captcha so I don't think you can do it in an automated way. But the tag applies to the whole address, not a specific transaction. So if you have a small number of addresses, you can tag them all so that all your transactions will have the link. If you are automatically generating addresses, that would be hard.

The first way is with a [signed message](https://blockchain.info/tags?form_type=0). You sign their specific message and send it to them. That means only you can tag your address this way.

The [second way is if an address is viewable on a website](https://blockchain.info/tags?form_type=1), then anyone can come along and tag the address so it links to that page.

These will allow you to make it look like the "DPR Seized Coins 2" in your example.

### Public Note

A separate thing is to use a public note like this message in your example:

> WTF??? What is it??? Is this guy CAN CLONE BTC? OR COPY BTC? Is it real? WTF??? Somebody can explain??? WTF!! I found this: http://sharma.binhoster.com

A note applies to a specific transaction, not an entire address. Also it does not require a captcha so it can be automated. But it can't have clickable links. [Here's information on how to do that.](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api)

Comment: +1 for responding and the answer what i was looking for... Thanks for the info. Let me have a try and then accept your answer on success